# Tab Bar Controller: Show Login Controller + Stop Double Tap on Tab Button

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application with a UITabBarController as the root view. I don't want my users to have to login to have a look at the app, so the first tab (Tab 1) is visible to all users. Now the other tabs should be locked behind a LoginViewController.

I have the following on the Locked Views:

ActivityViewController.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   if AccessToken.current != nil {
   // Do Stuff
   }
   else {
       let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserLoginViewController")
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:false)
   }
}
```

UserLoginViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if AccessToken.current != nil {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

// Functions to handle login omitted
// I do the following once login is successful
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

// Close button to return to first no login required tab (Tab 1)
@IBAction func closeButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // Send back to the first index in the tab bar controller
    self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

I have the following problem:

1. Pressing on a locked tab once, displays the login screen properly. Pressing the same tab again, will dismiss the login screen, animate to the view the login screen is hiding and then pop the login screen again. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is present your login controller `UserLoginViewController`, so it will show in front of `UITabBarController`. Then inside the login controller, add the dismiss action when login success

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
    // Do Stuff
}
else {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserLoginViewController")
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Ok let's say using self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil) I have new problems resulting from navigation bars not showing, the close button stops working and sending back to first tab in addition to the following new warning: "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged"

My aim is to maintain some ability to navigate through the app.

Comment: yes, navigation bar should be embed to the `UserLoginViewController` in order to have navigation bar. Just add UITabBarItem for the close button

Comment: In this case, you should present the UINavigationController of the `UserLoginViewController` instead of `UserLoginViewController`